# YUI Datatable - "Data Error."

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-datatable

I'm trying to make a datatable using YUI with JSON returned data.

Included is the json returned data, and the page data displayed.

***JSON Data:***

```
[{"supplier_id":"127","name":"Adams Farms","description":"","ofarm":"1","active":"1"},{"supplier_id":"141","name":"Barriger Farms","description":"","ofarm":"1","active":"1"}]
```

***Javascript for YUI:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function() {
    YAHOO.example.JSON = function() {
        var myColumnDefs = [
            {key:"supplier_id", label:"ID"},
            {key:"name", label:"Name"},
            {key:"description", label:"Notes"},
            {key:"ofarm", label:"Ofarm"},
            {key:"active", label:"Active"}
        ];

        var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource("ajax/select/supplier");
        myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
        myDataSource.responseSchema = {
            fields: ["supplier_id","name","description","ofarm","active"]
        };

        var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("json", myColumnDefs,
                myDataSource);

        return {
            oDS: myDataSource,
            oDT: myDataTable
        };
    }();
});
</script>
```

***Page View:***

> YUI Test *(header)*
>
> This example populates a DataTable with data. *(intro text)*
>
> ID - Name - Notes - Ofarm - Active   *(column titles)*
>
> Data error. *(returned data)*

Comment: I have also got a really simple example similar to this, I am getting the same result, does anybody have any suggestions? BTW this comes up as one of the first results on google when you search for yui json data error

Comment: @Pete Herbert Penito See bellow

Comment: Use JSARRAY as your type. Should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to YUI [dataSource](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/) page, YUI dataSource expectes an JavaScript object, not an array of objects. And when using JSON, use must set a *resultsList* on the responseSchema property. Something as (**Notice** dataSourceSettings.responseSchema.fields property)

```
(function() {
    var YdataTable  = YAHOO.widget.DataTable,
        YdataSource = YAHOO.util.DataSource;

    var settings = {
        container:"<DATATABLE_CONTAINER_GOES_HERE>",
        source:"<URL_TO_RETRIEVE_YOUR_DATA>",
        columnSettings:[
            {key:"supplier_id", label:"ID"},
            {key:"name", label:"Name"},
            {key:"description", label:"Notes"},
            {key:"ofarm", label:"Ofarm"},
            {key:"active", label:"Active"}
        ],
        dataSourceSettings:{
            responseType:YdataSource.TYPE_JSON,
            responseSchema:{
                resultsList:"<DOT_NOTATION_LOCATION_TO_RESULTS>",
                fields:[
                    {key:"supplier_id"},
                    {key:"name"},
                    {key:"description"},
                    {key:"ofarm"},
                    {key:"active"}
                ]
            }
        },
        dataTableSettings:{
            initialLoad:false
        }
    }

    var dataTable = new YdataTable(
                    settings.container, 
                    settings.columnSettings, 
                    new YdataSource(
                    settings.source, 
                    settings.dataSourceSettings), 
                    settings.dataTableSettings);
})();
```

Comment: This was a huge help, I put ResultSet and Result in my JSON and it worked, thanks!

Comment: The work around for your solution is to use "responseType:YdataSource.TYPE_JSARRAY". But yes, that will also work.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, I found this page when looking for the cause of "Data error" in a YUI datatable, and I eventually found out that I was missing the /build/connection/connection-min.js script reference on my web page.